# Correctly encoded string gets decoded when pushed into window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, hashchange

**The goal:** Correctly put a string from a `data` attribute into the `window.location.hash`.

**The code:**

```
map = {path: $(this).attr('data-path'), rev: $(this).attr('data-rev')};
window.location.hash = getMapParams(map);

function getMapParams(map) {
  s="";
  for(key in map) {
    value=eval("map."+key);
    if (s.length > 0) {
      s+="&";
    }
    s+=encodeURIComponent(key)+"="+encodeURIComponent(value);
  }
  return s;
}
```

**The problem:** As soon as the `data-path` attribute contains a space Firefox fails to put the hash correctly. The space will appear unencoded whereas in other browsers it's correctly encoded as `%20`.

**The weird quirks:** If I debug the code the string is listed *with* the encoded space.

**The research done:** I have found plenty solutions for correctly *reading* the hash in firefox. In one way or another this is working fine with my code.

**The question:** How do I stop Firefox from urldecoding the space(s) in a string I put in window.location.hash

Comment: In theory it's quite logical that firefox doesn't handle spaces in the hash, since it's supposed to refer to an `id=""` and scroll the page for you. Can't you use `_` or something instead?

Comment: May be not the answer, just try using value=map[key]; and return encodeURIComponent(s) only once all together at last.

Comment: I could replace all the spaces with another character but it's a frontend using the Dropbox api to fetch folders and files. I would have to change a lot of code. And on top of that in other browsers it's working fine. The thing is, it is not a space. It is an urlencoded space. Other urlencoded characters like `/` (`%2F`) are left as is..

Comment: The simple solution I guess is then through jQuery determine if the client is Firefox and decode/encode/replace space to correctly.

Comment: I went with Robin Castlin's solution above. But only replaced characters in my javascript code so I did not have to go into my PHP backend. It works as expected now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually try to avoid `window.location.hash` because of it's not uniform across browsers.

Thus rather than doing following

```
window.location.hash = "some hash value";
```

I would do

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split("#")[0] + "#" + encodeURIComponent("some hash value");
```

Furthermore, although Firefox shows decoded hash in address bar (i.e. ' '  instead of %20), if you try to copy the address it is actually encoded. Thus what is getting shown is not what is in the URI.

As an aside, I always access hash using following code

```
var hash_val = window.location.href.split("#")[1] || "";
```

Comment: I might indeed to a little rewriting and use location.href instead of the replace. I don't really like the ___ in the address bar. The weird thing is, the request that I subsequently built from the hash included the space, that's why it broke my code.

Comment: "Furthermore, although Firefox shows decoded hash in address bar (i.e. ' ' instead of %20), if you try to copy the address it is actually encoded" - that's a weird behaviour by Firefox! Thanks, you fixed my problem.